# store each string in sentence in reverse way

Tags: java, swing

i try with buffered string.reverse(); but i want reverse each word of sentence.
so i try with this..

```
 for(int a = 0;a <= msgLength; a++){
           temp += msg.charAt(a);
           if((msg.charAt(a) == '')||(a == msgLength)){
           for(int b = temp.length()-1; b >= 0; b--){
               encrypt_msg += temp.charAt(a);
               if((b == 0) && (a != msgLength))
                   encrypt_msg += "";
           }
           temp = "";
       }
       }
```

plz help me to simplify this logic.
string is user defined.
i wanted to print reversed string in jtextfields.

Comment: Split the sentence and reverse each String.

Comment: Friendly hint: in the future try capitalization ("I", "JTextFields", "String") and using full words ("please" instead of "plz"), that will usually improve the answers you get.

Comment: thank you sir, i will surely implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following simple code:

```
String sentence= "This is sentence";
String[] words=sentence.split(" ");
for(String word: words){
 System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word).reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a method named [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

you can separate the tokens using this method like this.

```
String s = "hello how are you";
String[] s2 = s.split(" ");
```

now s2 contains each word as array element.

now you can reverese by traversing the array.

Answer (score 0):

there your answer...

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
        String strRev="";

```
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     StringBuffer revers=new StringBuffer(st.nextToken());
     strRev=strRev+" "+revers.reverse().toString();
 }
```

try it..!!